# hibernate entity different implementation

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I have a project with multiple implementation and an entity class Person.
In every implementation there is a different database, different table and different columns.
In the DAO layer and the business layer the code is the same.
How can I change only the persistence layer to have different implementation of Person entity class based on a profile and keep unchanged the rest of the code?

```
//I would like to change table and columns based on a profile

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;


    private String first_name;
    private String last_name

    //getters,setters

}


//I would like to keep DAO unchanged no matter the profile
public interface PersonDao {
    public List<Person> listAll() throws Exception;
}

public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao{

    @Override
    public List<Person> listAll() throws Exception{


            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
            Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);

            ...the rest of the code
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a generic abstract Person and PersonDao which will be extended/implemented by other classes (e.g. MongoPerson, MysqlPersonDao, PersonV2... based on your requirements). But use only Person and PersonDao in your service layer.

Autowire with Spring using [qualifiers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) and [configurations](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-configuration-annotation/)